# Authorization window reopens then quickly closes even if already authorized. How to avoid this?

Tags: javascript, facebook, authorization

My App on Facebook uses the JavaScript SDK. When a user navigates to my app page and goes to my app, a popup asks them to authorize the app. This works well.

However, if they authorize the app, then return to it later, another pop-up (which i believe to be another authorization window) will quickly open then close.

What is my code is doing this? Code is below.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '221953271200525', // App ID
      channelURL : '//www.vidjahgames.com/fall/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here


FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');

     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 }, {scope: 'email'});


  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

FB.login makes the popup appear, so you should first know if the user is logged in and if not make the login popup appear:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.session) {
   // A user has logged in, and a new cookie has been saved
   FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        _userName = response.name;
        alert("hello"+_userName);
     }.bind(this));
 } else {
   FB.login(function(response) {
      // the rest of your code here...
   }

 }
});
```